# Expiring roles for users?

Tags: users

I have created few user roles and one of them should be an expiring role, which would be active only for a period of time (something like paid subscription - if user pay for new period of time, the account becomes fully active again). I know of [Role Expire](http://drupal.org/project/role_expire), but I'm not sure it's the right think - it wasn't updated in long time and first activating the module instantly created few error messages. Similiar thing (probably) with [Notifications](http://drupal.org/project/notifications).

Any hints how to achieve it? Use one of these modules? Or is there something more I couldn't find so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this would be using rules.

Rules allow you to execute some rules/action sometime in the future.

See http://dev.nodeone.se/node/1032 shows a great similar example.

Comment: Thanks, Rules helped me with few things, currently wondering how to solve the Subscriptions - still not sure how could I achieve what I want. Should I try implementing some sort of Pay Now module/script and then set the rules? Any more tips?